# How to Listen to Audio files from Email and Text people send without the phone going to sleep?

Tags: iphone

How can I Listen to Audio files from Emails and Texts people send without the phone going to sleep? iPhone 14 pro max.

If possible, I don't want the phone to never sleep. I'd like to see if when I'm playing audio, it stays awake. It seems simple.

I also find it hard to organize these files in a way that makes them easy to find for review later.

Please help.

iPhone Ignorant,

CajunBob